# Getting hung up on notation for $\frac{d}{dx}e^u$ vs. $\int{e^u}du$

Tags: calculus, integration

We know that $\frac{d}{dx}e^u = e^u \frac{du}{dx}$    <---Chain rule

So, that means $\int{e^u}du=e^u+C$

To verify this, we could take the derivative of the integral and make sure we got back to the original.

Well, $\frac{d}{dx}(e^u+C)=e^u \frac{du}{dx}+0$

So, it sort of matches, but doesn't exactly match what we started with.  The original just has $du$, while the derivative of the integral has $\frac{du}{dx}$

I am getting hung up on notation, I know, but why doesn't it go back to what we started with?

Comment: It's asymmetric because you took the derivative with respect to $x$, and the integral with respect to $u$.  The analogous integral is $\int\frac{du}{dx}e^udx=e^x+C$.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the notation $u = f(x)$, so that $e^u= e^{f(x)},$ it makes the situation clearer.

Then $$\color{blue} {(e^{f(x)} + C)' = e^{f(x)}\cdot f'(x)}$$

Now, $$\int e^{f(x)} \,dx \neq e^{f(x)} + C,\; \text{ unless } u = f(x) = x$$ but rather, $$\color{blue} {\int e^{f(x)} f'(x)\,dx = e^{f(x)}+C}$$

Comment: Unless $f'(x)=1$,since $f(x)=x+k$ also satisfies the condition

Comment: Yes, indeed it does.

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up $x$ and $u$, you basically have $u=x$ in your case, thus $\frac{du}{dx}=1$

Answer (score 0):

First note that
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left[e^{u(x)}+C\right]=\frac{d}{dx}\left[e^{u(x)}\right]=e^{u(x)}\frac{d}{dx}\left[u(x)\right] $$
So now 
$$ \int e^{u(x)}\frac{d}{dx}\left[u(x)\right]dx = \int e^{u(x)}d[u(x)]=e^{u(x)}+C $$